# how to catch "http: server closed idle connection" error

Tags: go, httprequest

In my go application I am getting the following error: "http: server closed idle connection". I would like to catch it and retry my http connection if it's encountered.

I found that this error comes from the "net/http" package and furthermore from the transport implementation. In particular it's defined [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/transport.go#L631)
I get it wrapped in `url.Error` but this is all I was able to find out. Do you know how I can actually catch this error?

Edit:
I am using [elastic search client](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2), which in turn is using the `net/http`. From the client I get the above mentioned error and would like to retry my elastic search request as being transient. For now the way I am catching transient errors is:

```
if urlErr, ok := err.(*url.Error); ok && (urlErr.Temporary() || urlErr.Err == io.EOF) {
    return retryRequest()

}
```

Comment: according to the comment, you should not get this error.  `error values for debugging and testing, not seen by users.`

Comment: are you writing a server or client? can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you using a current version of Go? Like zzn said, you shouldn't see that error because it should just trigger the client to retry the request.

Comment: @JimB this is what I thought. I am using current version 1.7.1. Do you think I should file a bug?

Comment: @Ela: the current version is go1.8, and you need an example of how to reproduce the error if you see this in go1.8 (and I would check master as well).

Comment: @JimB I have no way of reproducing it unfortunately as only see it in my logs. Could you tell me how the go version would matter (honest question)?

Comment: @Ela: the version matters because code changes and bugs get fixed. The diff between go1.7.1 and go1.8 is 6956 insertions and 1669 deletions in the http package alone. You should be able to just check for a `net.Error` and its `Temporary()` method. If you're going to retry on something that's not `Temporary`, you might as well retry on any error with an exponential backoff.

Comment: I am getting this sporadically in Go 1.8 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Comments in `net/http/transport.go` say this (located [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/97324858513735093a958a585cca6d5fc2780533/src/net/http/transport.go#L483)):

```
if err == errServerClosedIdle {
    // The server replied with io.EOF while we were trying to
    // read the response. Probably an unfortunately keep-alive
    // timeout, just as the client was writing a request.
    return true
}
```

Go will attempt to retry the request if it finds a non-nil `http.Request.GetBody` (found [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/97324858513735093a958a585cca6d5fc2780533/src/net/http/transport.go#L428)), so I think it is expected to retry the request (or provide a `GetBody` function).

As for the leading error cause, you might want to check server's keep-alive functionality, my guess is that server is sending TCP connection reset (interpreted as `io.EOF`) prematurely. You might want to try disabling keep-alives and see if that changes anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I posted this question a long time ago and don't have enough context to know if this is a satisfactory answer.

Comment: That's fine, I myself experienced the same issue and was hunting it down for a long time (and stumbled upon this question multiple times), so I decided to at least document it.

Answer (score 4):

As Gray Fox mentioned, Go will usually retry these requests. However, this is not the case for requests that aren't "idempotent". I was running into a few of these errors on `POST` requests, and after searching around I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19943) that says:

> The HTTP Transport would normally retry those requests, but because they're POST requests they're not idempotent and Go conservatively assumes it might be unsafe to retry them.

Later in the issue someone mentioned that many banking APIs use some variant of the `Idempotent-Key` header to make them "safe". Stripe is a company that uses that header, and this is what [their API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests) say about it:

> The API supports idempotency for safely retrying requests without accidentally performing the same operation twice.

So there you go, that's what the header is for.

In short, if you want Go's HTTP Transport to retry POST requests (and other non-idempotent requests), you need to include either the `Idempotency-Key` or `X-Idempotency-Key` header. That doesn't necessarily make those requests idempotent, but it will make them retry-able from `net/http`'s perspective.

Links:

- Source code check for the Idempotency-Key headers - https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2cd2ff6f564dce5be0c4fb7f06338ff7af3fc9a9/src/net/http/request.go#L1401)
- Github issue where I found this information: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19943